# Maximum of function

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} (n \in \mathbb{N})$ and $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then it doesn't generally hold that there exists a $\max_{x \in D} f(x)$, i.e. that there is a $\overline{x} \in D$ such that $f(\overline{x}) \geq f(x)$ for each $x \in D$.

For example if $n=1$ and $f(x)=x$, $D=(0,1)$ then $f$ doesn't have a maximum in $(0,1)$. Give examples for $n \geq 2$.

Hint: $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$ and find a space $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ so that $f$ has't maximum in $D$.

How can we show that $f(x)=x$ doesn't have a maximum in $D=(0,1)$ ?

I have tried the following in order to show it:

We suppose that $f$ has a maximum in $(0,1)$.

Then there is a $\overline{x} \in D$ such that $f(\overline{x}) \geq f(x) \Rightarrow \overline{x} \geq x$.

How can we find a contradiction?

Also how can we find a $D$ such that $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$ doesn't have a maximum in $D$ ?

**EDIT**: Is the following right?

We consider $D=((1,1), (2,2))$.

If the maximum is in $((1,1),(2,2))$, it is stricly less than $(2,2)$, say it is $(2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$. From the density of rationals, we have that there are $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2- \epsilon_1< q_1< 2$ and  $2- \epsilon_2< q_2< 2 $.

But then $(q_1, q_2 ) \in ((1,1), (2,2))$ and $(q_1, q_2)> (2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$.

Thus, $(2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$ cannot be the maximum and so we have found a contradiction.

Therefore, if $n=2$ and $f(x_1, x_2)=x_1+x_2$, $D=((1,1), (2,2))$ then $f$ doesn't have a maximum in $D$.

**EDIT 2**:

Would it be right as follows? $$$$

We consider $D=((1,1), (2,2))$.

If the maximum is in $((1,1),(2,2))$, it holds that  $\max_{x \in D} f(x)\subset (2,2)$, say it is $(2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$. From the density of rationals, we have that there are $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2- \epsilon_1< q_1< 2$ and  $2- \epsilon_2< q_2< 2 $.

But then $(q_1, q_2 ) \in ((1,1), (2,2))$ and $ (2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2) \subset (q_1, q_2)$. Thus $(2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$ cannot be the maximum.

$$$$
In general, can we find an open interval $D$ such that a function $f$ has a maximum in it?

Comment: Hint: if the maximum is in $(0,1)$ it is strictly less than 1, say it is $1-\epsilon$. Is there any number greater than $1-\epsilon$ but still less than 1?

Comment: Then from the density of rationals we have that there is a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $1- \epsilon<q<1$. Thus we found a number ($q$) that is in $(0,1)$ and is greater than $1- \epsilon$. So we found a contradiction. Is it right? @MiguelAtencia

Comment: @MiguelAtencia I have also edited my post writing a $D$ such that$f(x_1, x_2)=x_1+x_2$ hasn't a maximum in $D$. Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: If you grasp that the key point is that the interval must be open, right, but it is a bit sloppy, because you cannot speak about an order in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\bar{x}_1<2$ and $\bar{x}_2<2$, then $x_1+x_2>\bar{x}_1+\bar{x}_2$... yeah, I think these problems are tedious when you have understood the point.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Ah I see... But would it be right as follows? $$$$

We consider $D=((1,1), (2,2))$.

If the maximum is in $((1,1),(2,2))$, it holds that  $\max_{x \in D} f(x)\subset (2,2)$, say it is $(2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$. From the density of rationals, we have that there are $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2- \epsilon_1< q_1< 2$ and  $2- \epsilon_2< q_2< 2 $.

But then $(q_1, q_2 ) \in ((1,1), (2,2))$ and $ (2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2) \subset (q_1, q_2)$. Thus $(2- \epsilon_1, 2-\epsilon_2)$ cannot be the maximum.

Comment: You are apparently not even requiring that D be bounded!

Comment: What do you mean? In which case do we have to require it? @almagest

Comment: I meant that it is particularly easy to find examples if we allow D to be unbounded.

Comment: What example could we consider for example if we let $D$ to be unbounded? And also can we find an open bounded interval so that $f$ has not a maximum in it?